# Could not load 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2' using Quartz + Autofac + DynamicProxy + Topshelf

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, autofac, castle-dynamicproxy, topshelf

I'm basically trying to intercept methods on quartz Jobs.

Using Standard Topshelf code, Class intercepting in IoC registration, AdoJobStore

The interceptor gets called for every method on a `IJob`. 
I have code that runs before calling `Scheduler.Start()` that checks each job and using the getters and methods, and it works when called manually. 
But when the scheduler starts, an exception is thrown from Quartz method `AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.RetrieveJob(...)`.

Exception:

`Quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve job because the BLOB couldn't be deserialized: Could not load file or assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Has any one had this issue or knows some way to resolve? Much appreciated

Comment: DynamicProxyGenAssembly2 is the assembly that is dynamically generated by the Castle proxy generator http://www.castleproject.org/, I could take a guess that the proxy assembly is failing to load some other assembly. To work this out look at the bind failures from the fusion logger https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Nothing turns up when logging binding failures and can't see it when loggin all bindings.
I do get this in my normal logs:
```c#
Pre-bind state information    
LOG: DisplayName   DynamicProxyGenAssembly2
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: DynamicProxyGenAssembly2   Domain ID: 1
```And then it tries to download it from my debug/bin folder. When I check my bin folder there's no sign of `DynamicProxyGenAssembly2  `

Comment: Yeah, the assembly is created in memory, so you won't see it anywhere in the file system. If I were you I would download the quartz scheduler source code and step through it to get more of an idea what is going wrong. I seriously doubt it is an issue with the castle proxy as everyone uses that for generating runtime proxies.

Comment: Yea it seems to be a quartz issue. Interception actually works, until the jobs are scheduled and the `JobFactory` tries to retrieve (initialize) jobs.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. In my case its complaining about the namespace of the class used in the payload.